# Nodejs terminal console shows a lot of stuff

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, ubuntu

When I run an app in Nodejs using "nodejs app" and do some tasks in the app, the log shows a lot of stuff and I have to search for what I just did in the terminal for a long time.

Example:

When I hit an API, I get :

```
127.0.0.1 - - [Wed, 24 Sep 2014 10:05:15 GMT] "GET /js/controller.js HTTP/1.1" 200 - "htt://localhost:5555/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [Wed, 24 Sep 2014 10:05:15 GMT] "GET /js/service.js HTTP/1.1" 200 - "htt://localhost:5555/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [Wed, 24 Sep 2014 10:05:16 GMT] "GET /partials/patient/view.html HTTP/1.1" 200 - "htt://localhost:5555/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [Wed, 24 Sep 2014 10:05:16 GMT] "GET /images/no_image.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 - "htt://localhost:5555/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0"
```

Can someone help me get just the simple logs without all this gecko ... and stuff.
All I want to see in my console is logs like
`GET /js/service.js 200`

I was able to get just that in the previous version of Nodejs and Ubuntu but not here. Note: I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Well, you have what you need, just a little more verbose, see if there is a flag that make node js quieter. What version of node and what app are you using?

Comment: I am using v0.10.25 of nodejs and I am creating my own webapp. I just want to see the console logs and the api calls not all these informations.

Comment: Are you sure you don t have any `console.log(something)` that could produce this type of message? If so, could you give us the relevant part of code?

Comment: Also, what is the api you are calling?

Comment: I don't understand, are you developping the API and seeing this log in the server console, or are you creating a client for this API ? Which framework/modules are you using ?

Comment: Are you using `express` with `morgan`?  If so, I have an answer.

Comment: I have the api it is just that the log seems to be too dirty. Nothing is wrong else. I get similar web logs in all my other projects as well so it is not the issue of api. I am using express, jade, debug, bcrypt and mysql. I didn't use to have this issue in ubuntu 12.04 but then I decided to update and re installed nodejs and all. Since then I have this issue

Comment: @MatthewBakaitis I am not using morgan, but can you tell me the answer anyway, it might help. thanks

Comment: If you were using morgan for this kind of logging, it would be a configuration change.  If you aren't using morgan...what are you using to generate the logs?  Node does not output to the console by default. Some module you are using or code you wrote is doing that...what's the API based upon?